# Sizing instantantiated view controllers in a UIPageViewController?

Tags: swift3, swift4, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, uicontainerview

My UIPageViewController is reached by an “embed” segue in a container view that is a part of another view controller on my story board. The issue I am having is the container view that is embedding the UIPageViewController is not properly fitting the instantiated view controllers. I want to be able to see the instantiated view controllers in their entirety within the container view.

In case the above wording is unclear, let me try rephrasing it. The UIPageViewController I created has a variable that holds a three view controller instantiated array, but the contents in those instantiated view controllers are not showing up in their entirety in  the container view that is embedding the UIPageViewController.

I am new here so please forgive me if I’m unclear on something. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: have you declared the constraints  ?

Comment: @Tobi I have declared constraints in the instantiated view controllers but I cannot see the constrained contents because they are off screen in my container view

Comment: alright , can you provide some code to this please

Comment: @Tobi what would be the easiest way for me to send you all a .zip of the project? I am unfamiliar with GutHub but I can look into that more if that’s the only way I can send it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728934/swift-4-resizing-a-viewcontroller-to-fit-in-a-pageview-within-a-containerview This is exactly my issue!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your project, but... I have a simple example of embedding a `UIPageViewController` in a container view here: https://github.com/DonMag/EmbeddedPageView ... the "pages" have labels at the corners, to make it easy to see they are being sized correctly. (While not part of your question, the example also has buttons in the "main" view to programmatically control the page changes, just so you know the purpose if you look at this example.)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `clipsToBounds` to `false` on container view:
`yourContainerView.clipsToBounds = false`

Comment: The container view has “Clip to Bounds” unchecked on the storyboard

Comment: But no luck. Sorry, I forgot to include that in my first comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728934/swift-4-resizing-a-viewcontroller-to-fit-in-a-pageview-within-a-containerview This is exactly my issue!